# How to show a diff between two buffers with "character-level" diffs

Tags: ediff, diff-mode

When two buffers are compared for differences, `M-x ediff-buffers` does not indicate the specific characters that have changed within a word (ie "character-level" diffs). Most modern diff tools will show the diffs within a word.

Emacs seems to be missing this important (or obviously useful?) feature by default. How can I make Emacs display the diffs by character?

**Update**
Here's `M-x ediff-buffers diff1 diff2`, using `emacs -Q` to ensure that my theme is not interferring:
[image]

Here's the same text pasted into Meld:
[image]

Comment: It looks like this problem is related to the theme you're using. In vanilla Emacs (24.4), differences between individual lines are highlighted. You can verify this by starting Emacs via `emacs -Q` and calling `ediff-buffers` on `diff1` and `diff2` as you normally would.

Comment: I tried running with `emacs -Q`, added above. Also, I modified my question to address *character-level* diffs instead of *intra-line* diffs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
(setq-default ediff-forward-word-function 'forward-char)
```

Answer (score 6):

This feature is called "refining" in Ediff.  You can hit `*` to refine the current hunk, or `@` to turn on automatic refining whenever you move to a different hunk.

Comment: I modified my question to address the *character-level* diffs instead of the *intra-line* diffs. Is it possible to make Emacs show the diffs within a word?